# Unable to connect Oracle 10

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, oracle-xe

I installed **oracle 10** on my system but this is what prompt when I clicked on start database icon

> c\oraclelexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>net start OracleXETNSlistener System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied
>
> c\oraclelexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>net start OracleserviceXE System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied
>
> c\oraclelexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>_

Comment: Did you try to run as `Administrator`?

Comment: But sir, the "Get Started with Oracle Database 10g express Edition" icon only connecting with file://c:/oraclexe/app/oracle/doc/geting_started.htm And it was unable to connect when I typed http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex directly on my browser. Also my Toad for Oracle gives notified that "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor". Please help me out.